# How to use cmd on windows for accessing linux server with localhost:8080 for MySql Database?

Tags: mysql, windows

When i access MySql from mysql bin folder command prompt then its working fine. but when go with cmd to access localhost:8080 then its not working properly. I use this command for it:

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin> mysql -u root -p  -h localhost:8080

Comment: Is mysql really listening on port `8080`? Shouldn't it be `3306`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is mysql really listening on port `8080`? Shouldn't it be `3306`?

Take a look into `my.ini` and check the definition in the `[mysqld]` section:

```
[mysqld]
; ...
port        = 3306
; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change MySQL default port 3306 to 8080.Find the find MySQL configuration file, in general "my.ini" than edit the line:

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

to

```
[mysqld]
port = 8080
```

Then restart MySQL service, it's done.